# Most efficient way to paint columns in django template / view

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an app where I allow the users to create a customized dashboard containing 'widgets'.   They can choose 1,2 or 3 columns and then select widget column and widget order.

The widgets will be of differing heights so have to paint in columns rather than rows.

I loop through the widgets and annotate with a colno and then send this to the template.  during initial dev I've just looped through them all in the template and am now looking to make this a little more efficient.

I would expect between 15-20 widgets per page.

in the template at the moment I have:

```html
<div class="column">         
   {% for widget in widgets %}
      {% if widget.colno == 1 %}
          {% include 'widget.html' %}
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}    
   
 </div>
 
 <div class="column">         
   {% for widget in widgets %}
      {% if widget.colno == 2 %}
          {% include 'widget.html' %}
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}    
   
 </div>
 <div class="column"> etc  </div>
```

Obviously not the most efficient way to do this.   Wondering if there are better ways that this could be done:

a) Iterate through in the view and assign widgets to dictionaries based on their colno.  Then iterate through these in the template.  - I have tried this approach and actually seems to be slower than the original approach which surprised me.

b) on create/edit of the dashboard keep var for "column_widget_count" then loop using these counters (this might be tricky to keep updated)

c) some other sexy Django template/tag approach that I am unaware of..

I should also mention that I am sorting the widgets in order of column and then order within a column.

Request for backend code provided below.   I have widget object and child widget items.   Allocating to different dictionaries as show below seems to be slower than sending in one dictionary and then looping in the template as above.  Thanks again

```html
layout = Layout.objects.get(id=layout_id)

widgets = Widget.objects.prefetch_related('widgetitem','widgetitem__indicator').filter(layouts=layout).annotate(             colno=F('layoutwidgets__widget_column')).order_by(
                'layoutwidgets__widget_order')



widgets_colone = []
widgets_coltwo = []
widgets_colthree = []

for widget in widgets:
    if widget.colno == 1:
        widgets_colone.append(widget)
    elif widget.colno == 2:
        widgets_coltwo.append(widget)
    else:
        widgets_colthree.append(widget)

context['widgets_colone'] = widgets_colone
context['widgets_coltwo'] = widgets_coltwo
context['widgets_colthree'] = widgets_colthree

return render(request,'three_column_dashboard.html', context)
```

Comment: can you add your backend code too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.